# HttpSolrServer with proxy

Tags: java, solr, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x, solrj

Using the HttpSolrServer to connect to a Solr instance. Trying to run this through a proxy but currently the configuration doesn't look to be getting applied, it continues using the baseUrl. This is the code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 128);
params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST, 32);
params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, false);
params.set(HttpClientUtil.PROP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, this.connectionTimeout);

httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        AuthScope.ANY,
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword)
);

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, proxyPort, proxyProtocol);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);


HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(baseUrl, httpClient);
```

Have also tried:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(this.connectionTimeout)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(this.connectionTimeout)
    .setSocketTimeout(this.connectionTimeout)
    .build();

HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
    .setMaxConnTotal(128)
    .setMaxConnPerRoute(32)
    .disableRedirectHandling();

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyUrl, proxyPort, proxyProtocol);
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(proxyUrl, proxyPort, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "basic"),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));

httpClientBuilder
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .setTargetAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy())
    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();


HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(baseUrl, httpClient);
```

Versions

- SolrJ 4.7.2
- HttpClient 4.3.1

Comment: Can you add details of solr, sorj, and http client jar using for the above. You can check yourself too, as the way you connect to solr is different from solr 5

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: 3 years is a looooong time sorry :P